# unit test a Grails service that implements org.springframework.context.ResourceLoaderAware

Tags: spring, grails

I have a grails service that implements org.springframework.context.ResourceLoaderAware. When I attempt to run my junit test for the service the resourceLoader is always null. I suspect it is due to the environment not being loaded. However, there should be a way...

Do I need to use an integration test instead of unit??

Code example is always appreciated

Comment: any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It will work in an integration test. In the unit test you will have to set/stub the `resourceLoader` yourself.